# PhpMyAdmin Grant and privileges

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

it is possible to have a configuration like this on phpmyadmin?
I have 3 user:

- Root
- Admin
- User

with:

- DB_1
- DB_2
- DB_3

**Root** have `all` privileges (create user/db..etc) , **User** have `USAGE` privileges and i would that the **Admin** have all privilages (create db/delate etc..) but can not see in any way the DB_1
**Summary**: Its possible lock the DB_1 for **Admin**? The admin user must be an administrator but does not have to see the contents of the DB_1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of solution. You can use like `mask` by username for accessing to diffent DBs.When you click `Add user`, see section `Database for user` and `Grant all privileges on wildcard name (username\_%)`. It means that user can then create a database with the prefix only and will not be visible to others.